# Relative imports in pythonanywhere do not work in flask project

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I am trying to learn from a very helpful tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-authentication-to-your-app-with-flask-login

on how to use flask_login.

My question: **The complete tutorial works fine for me on my local PC, however I run into problems when trying to get this running on pythonanywhere**.

The error seems ot be related to relative imports. In the best case, I want to come up with some code which runs both locally on my machine and on pythonanywhere.

For a minimal example, the project structure is as follows:

```
└── flask_auth_app
    └── project
        ├── __init__.py       
        ├── auth.py           
        ├── main.py
```

with the files

**`__init__.py`**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# init SQLAlchemy so we can use it later in our models
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret-key-goes-here'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'

    db.init_app(app)

    # blueprint for auth routes in our app
    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    # blueprint for non-auth parts of app
    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    return app
```

**auth.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint
from . import db

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    return 'Login'

@auth.route('/signup')
def signup():
    return 'Signup'

@auth.route('/logout')
def logout():
    return 'Logout'
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint
from . import db

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Index'

@main.route('/profile')
def profile():
    return 'Profile'
```

To execute this on my local PC, I create an environment variable

```
set FLASK_APP=project
```

and run flask from the flask_auth_app directory

```
flask run
```

and everything runs fine.

I have now transferred the files to pythonanywhere and use the following configuration there:

```
source code: /home/grammaster/flask_auth_app
working directory: /home/grammaster/flask_auth_app
```

**WSGI configuration file**

```
# This file contains the WSGI configuration required to serve up your
# web application at http://<your-username>.pythonanywhere.com/
# It works by setting the variable 'application' to a WSGI handler of some
# description.
#
# The below has been auto-generated for your Flask project

import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = '/home/grammaster/flask_auth_app/project'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

# import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from project import app as application  # noqa
```

The resulting error message is

```
2021-08-13 05:58:26,704: Error running WSGI application
2021-08-13 05:58:26,706: ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'project' (/home/grammaster/flask_auth_app/./project/__init__.py)
2021-08-13 05:58:26,706:   File "/var/www/grammaster_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2021-08-13 05:58:26,707:     from project import app as application  # noqa
```

If I change the settings to

```
source code: /home/grammaster/flask_auth_app/project
working directory: /home/grammaster/flask_auth_app/project
```

and use

```
from main import app as application  # noqa
```

the resulting error is

```
2021-08-13 06:10:53,086: Error running WSGI application
2021-08-13 06:10:53,089: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
2021-08-13 06:10:53,089:   File "/var/www/grammaster_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2021-08-13 06:10:53,089:     from main import app as application  # noqa
2021-08-13 06:10:53,089: 
2021-08-13 06:10:53,089:   File "/home/grammaster/flask_auth_app/project/main.py", line 2, in <module>
2021-08-13 06:10:53,089:     from . import db
```

I am sure that the problem is rather trivial, but I seem to lack some basic understanding of relative imports on pythonanywhere and a flask server in general.

Comment: Where did you create the app variable? I didn't see it in the code.

Comment: The app variable is created in `__init__.py`. I understand that the create_app function is somehow automatically executed when starting the flask server.

Comment: Perhaps this tutorial will help you to understand relative imports enough to get them working https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent, otherwise, maybe just switch to using full imports, since they are significantly easier to understand

Comment: @Glenn This tutorial is definitely helpful, thank you. I think that I have understood the relative import part meanwhile, however, the remaining problems seem to originate from the way pythonanywhere invokes flask, assuming a certain configuration which I have not fully understood yet. The packacke with relative imports as listed above runs on my local PC, the problem is only the adaptation to pythonanywhere, most probably transferring the SET FLASK_APP command to a configuration pythonanywhere can understand

Comment: Not nice at all, but I have put everything into one file now and this works.

Comment: Relative imports seem to be an issue on pythonanywhere: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/NoSuchFileOrDirectory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the solution of getting the above example working with relative imports and on pythonanywhere. The problem was originating from wrong paths in the WSGI configuration file.

For the example and the paths above, the **correct WSGI configuration file** is

```
# This file contains the WSGI configuration required to serve up your
# web application at http://<your-username>.pythonanywhere.com/
# It works by setting the variable 'application' to a WSGI handler of some
# description.
#
# The below has been auto-generated for your Flask project

import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = '/home/grammaster/flask_auth_app'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

# import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from project import create_app
application = create_app()
```